# Table fontsize too small after using \resizebox

Tags: tables, fonts, columns, resize, column-width

Initially, I had the problem of my table not fitting the column width of the page however after a \resizebox that was corrected however at the cost of the font size, is there a way to fix this? Thank you,

```
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet2'
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Failure Modes and Effects Analysis}
    \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{p{18.945em}p{13.22em}p{14.5em}cp{15.335em}p{20em}p{5.11em}p{16.835em}}

            Aviation Safety Investigation Reports\newline{} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Functional Failure Mode}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Failure Effect}} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Item/Part/Component}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Failure}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{13.555em}}{\textbf{Probability /\newline{}Mode failure rates}} & \textbf{Effect on item/component\newline{}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Effect on Aircraft}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Severity}} & \textbf{Failure Detection Method (A: crew; B: on\newline{}the ground)\newline{}\newline{}} \\
            AAIB Report on DHC-8-402 Dash 8 G-JECF Serious Incident (2004)\newline{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1 Input Output Processor} & Intermittent electrical contact arising from cracked\newline{}solder on two pins of a transformer on the IOP power\newline{}supply module\newline{} & \multicolumn{1}{p{13.555em}}{-} & Loss of cockpit indications: left fuel inlet temperature,  left main oil pressure  and hydraulic quantity for systems No 1 and No 3\newline{}\newline{} & Misleading data to primary flight display\newline{} & Major & IOP 1 fail\newline{}or IOP 2 FAIL is displayed as an advisory message on\newline{}the Engine and System Integrated Display  \\
            AAIU Report on B737-800 EI-DHI Serious Incident (2012)\newline{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Pitot Probe} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{short circuit within the pitot probe} & 1x10-9 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Loss of anti-ice functions} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Airspeed disagreement} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Minor} & Unannunciated,   IAS indications were diverging and that IAS Disagree warnings\newline{}illuminated on both PFDs\newline{} \\
            BEA Report on Dassault Falcon 7X HB-JFN Serious Incident (2011)\newline{}\newline{} & Horizontal Stabilizer Electronic Control Unit\newline{} & Part damage, material property\newline{}degraded, eroded and aging, soldering defect on an HSECU induction coil pin \newline{} & -     & Noise,  loss of 15  Volt power and potential latent failure\newline{} & Loss of power\newline{}boost, noise, Loss of speed\newline{}and direction\newline{}interpretation, no\newline{}motor drive for\newline{}actuator,  Assy or system\newline{}level parameters,\newline{}tolerances\newline{}affected; otherwise latent\newline{} & Major & A) Uncommanded\newline{}movement of actuator,\newline{}detectable by external\newline{}position sensors\newline{}B) Vendor test/evaluate;\newline{}Box ATP.\newline{} \\
        \end{tabular}}
    \label{tab:addlabel}%
    \caption[]{This table displays information on the FMEA of all the failure modes from the 3 Aviation Safety Investigation Reports mentioned above.}
\end{table}%
```

Comment: Generally, do not use `resizebox` on tables. Instead you can take a look at the `tabularx` package.

Comment: Please add the documentclass you use. You mention columnwidth. I assume you have a twocolumn document. Is that correct? Are you sure, your table will ever fit into one column of a twocolumn document? You have a total of 8 columns and quite a lot of text in them. Probably using `table*` and allowing the table to be as wide as both columns would be better.

Comment: After having had a closer look at the table and its contents I even doubt it is going to fit into a portrait oriented a4 page while still keeping the font size reasonably large. Probably you will even have to use a landscape page and do quite a lot of redesigning in order to make the table fit ( and look good).

Comment: Will you add more reports later on or will your table only contain the three reports you already added?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my suggestion based on `tabularx`, a smaller font size and the assuumption of a `twocolumn` `article` class:

[image]

Here is also  a second example in which I have split the table in half:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
%\begin{landscape}
\begin{table*}[htbp]
    \centering
    \footnotesize
    \caption{Failure Modes and Effects Analysis of different Aviation Safety Investigation Reports}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{LLLLLcL}
\toprule
   \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{Functional Failure Mode}} 
    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\thead{Failure Effect}} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-3} \cmidrule(l){4-7}
   \thead{Item/\\ Part/\\ Component} 
    & \thead{Failure}
      & \thead{Probability/\\ Mode failure\\ rates} 
        & \thead{Effect on\\ item/\\ component} 
          & \thead{Effect on\\ Aircraft}
            & \thead{Severity} 
              & \thead{Failure\\Detection\\ Method} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{7}{@{}l}{AAIB Report on DHC-8-402 Dash 8 G-JECF Serious Incident (2004)} \\ \addlinespace
   1 Input Output Processor 
    & Intermittent electrical contact arising from cracked solder on two pins of a transformer on the IOP power\newline{}supply module
      & -
        & Loss of cockpit indications: left fuel inlet temperature,  left main oil pressure  and hydraulic quantity for systems No 1 and No 3
          & Misleading data to primary flight display
            & Major 
              & IOP 1 failor IOP 2 FAIL is displayed as an advisory message on the Engine and System Integrated Display  \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{7}{@{}l}{AAIU Report on B737-800 EI-DHI Serious Incident (2012)}\\ \addlinespace
   Pitot Probe
    & short circuit within the pitot probe 
      & 1x10-9 
        & Loss of anti-ice functions 
          & Airspeed disagreement 
            & Minor
              & Unannunciated,   IAS indications were diverging and that IAS Disagree warnings illuminated on both PFDs \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{7}{@{}l}{BEA Report on Dassault Falcon 7X HB-JFN Serious Incident (2011)}\\   \addlinespace
   Horizontal Stabilizer Electronic Control Unit
    & Part damage, material property degraded, eroded and aging, soldering defect on an HSECU induction coil pin 
      & -     
        & Noise,  loss of 15  Volt power and potential latent failure  
          & Loss of power boost, noise, Loss of speed and direction interpretation, no motor drive for actuator,  Assy or system level parameters, tolerances affected; otherwise latent  
            & Major 
              & crew: Uncommanded movement of actuator, detectable by external position sensors; on the ground: Vendor test/evaluate; Box ATP.  \\
\bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
    \label{tab:addlabel}%
%    \caption[]{This table displays information on the FMEA of all the failure modes from the 3 Aviation Safety Investigation Reports mentioned above.}
\end{table*}%
%\end{landscape}


\begin{table*}[htbp]
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}
    \centering
    \caption{Failure Modes and Effects Analysis of different Aviation Safety Investigation Reports}
    \begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
    \caption{Functional Failure Modes}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{\quad}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3.75cm}Xc}
\toprule
   Item/ Part/ Component 
    & Failure
      & \thead{Probability/\\ Mode failure rates} 
 \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\itshape AAIB Report on DHC-8-402 Dash 8 G-JECF Serious Incident (2004)} \\ \addlinespace
   1 Input Output Processor 
    & Intermittent electrical contact arising from cracked solder on two pins of a transformer on the IOP power supply module
      & -
\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\itshape AAIU Report on B737-800 EI-DHI Serious Incident (2012)}\\ \addlinespace
   Pitot Probe
    & short circuit within the pitot probe 
      & 1x10-9 
\\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\itshape BEA Report on Dassault Falcon 7X HB-JFN Serious Incident (2011)}\\   \addlinespace
   Horizontal Stabilizer Electronic Control Unit
    & Part damage, material property degraded, eroded and aging, soldering defect on an HSECU induction coil pin 
      & -     
\\
\bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
\end{subtable}
\medskip

\begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
\caption{Failure Effects}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{\quad}LLcL}
\toprule
         Effect on item/ component 
          & Effect on Aircraft
            & Severity 
              & Failure Detection Method \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\itshape AAIB Report on DHC-8-402 Dash 8 G-JECF Serious Incident (2004)} \\ \addlinespace
         Loss of cockpit indications: left fuel inlet temperature,  left main oil pressure  and hydraulic quantity for systems No 1 and No 3
          & Misleading data to primary flight display
            & Major 
              & IOP 1 failor IOP 2 FAIL is displayed as an advisory message on the Engine and System Integrated Display  \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\itshape AAIU Report on B737-800 EI-DHI Serious Incident (2012)}\\ \addlinespace
       Loss of anti-ice functions 
          & Airspeed disagreement 
            & Minor
              & Unannunciated,   IAS indications were diverging and that IAS Disagree warnings illuminated on both PFDs \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\itshape BEA Report on Dassault Falcon 7X HB-JFN Serious Incident (2011)}\\   \addlinespace
     Noise,  loss of 15  Volt power and potential latent failure  
          & Loss of power boost, noise, Loss of speed and direction interpretation, no motor drive for actuator,  Assy or system level parameters, tolerances affected; otherwise latent  
            & Major 
              & crew: Uncommanded movement of actuator, detectable by external position sensors; on the ground: Vendor test/evaluate; Box ATP.  \\
\bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
\end{subtable}
    \label{tab:addlabel}%
%    \caption[]{This table displays information on the FMEA of all the failure modes from the 3 Aviation Safety Investigation Reports mentioned above.}
\end{table*}%
\end{document}
```